# Running CKQuery in AppDelegate - wait until done

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, cloudkit

I am trying to retrieve data from iCloud using CloudKit. Because I only want to do this once, I put my code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the AppDelegate.swift file.

I am trying to run this on the main thread, so the code I have in my first ViewController doesn't get called until I have gotten the data.

```
func getPeople() {
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Person", predicate: Predicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
        if error == nil {
            names.removeAll()
            messages.removeAll()
            pictures.removeAll()
            recordIds.removeAll()

            for record in records! {

                names.append(record.object(forKey: "name") as! String)
                messages.append(record.object(forKey: "message") as! String)
                pictures.append(UIImage(data: record.object(forKey: "picture") as! NSData as Data)!)
                recordIds.append(record.recordID)

            }

            print("done")

        } else {

            print(error)
            print(error?.code)

        }

    }

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(getPeople), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)

    return true
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. The `print("done")` gets called after `viewDidLoad` in my ViewController. I haven't worked with multi-threading before, and I would like to know how can I stop other code from being called until my query is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't wait until the data is loaded. It can take seconds to retrieve it and the user interface would be non responsive. And if it is non-responsive for too long,  the system can even terminate your app. Instead, update your views after the data arrive. You can use `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver` to observe the data change.